# SQL counting in a group by

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table like the following

```
C1 | C2 | C3

aa | bb | cc
aa | dd | tt
jj | uu | yy
aa | bb | cc
jj | rr | pp
```

C1 and C2 may may apear in any combination and may repeat values. Each C3 value is unique to a C2 value. I need to query the table to get all different values in C1 and no of times the map to different values in C2. in descending order(descending order isn't necessary). But the need to be grouped by C1 like follows

```
C1 | C2 |count| C3

aa | bb | 2   | cc
aa | dd | 1   | tt
jj | uu | 1   | yy
jj | rr | 1   | pp
```

Whats the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

This can be done using an aggregate function with a GROUP BY on the `C1`, `C2`, and `C3` columns. Since you group by these 3 columns, the count will be a total of the rows that match:

```
select C1, C2, count(*) Total, C3
from yourtable
group by C1, C2, C3
order by C1, total desc
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/858ff/4)

Comment: BUT THIS ORDERS THE WHOLE TABLE BY TOTAL. i NEED TO ORDER IT WITHIN THE GROUPS OF C1

Comment: @user2109362 Then you just need to expand on the ORDER BY to include `C1`, see my edit

Answer (score 0):

```
select C1, C2, Count(1), C3
from mytable
group by C1, C2, C3
order by 3 desc
```